# Artifactory - Hide NuGet Package Version From Visual Studio Feed

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, artifactory

Currently we are using Artifactory Professional version 4.16.0 to host all of of our NuGet packages. Recently there has been a need to "hide" older versions of a certain package from our feed in order to prevent users from installing it. We still need the package to be available as some of our legacy applications reference older packages (and they can't be updated for various reasons) therefore our CI requires the packages be available when it does a NuGet restore.

Is there a setting or a configuration to make a specific version of a package invisible in the feed? If so how can I go about doing that?

For example, in Visual Studio *MyPackage.1.0.0.nupkg* can not be seen on the feed by users however CI can still request it and do a NuGet restore on it. *MyPackage.2.0.0.nupkg* can be seen on the feed.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a setting or a configuration to make a specific version of a package invisible in the feed? If so how can I go about doing that?

According to the [NuGet Repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/NuGet+Repositories), I am afraid there is no such configuration for Artifactory to make a specific version of a package invisible in the feed.

As a workaround, you can add [Package versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/package-versioning) to the package on the `packages.config` or `PackageReference`, for example, add the `allowedVersions="(9.0.1,11.0.1]"` to the package `Newtonsoft.Json`:

```
<packages>
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="11.0.1" allowedVersions="(9.0.1,11.0.1]" targetFramework="net462" />
</packages>
```

After with this setting, when you open the nuget package manager UI, the version of 9.0.1 and below could not be selected:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's unfortunate that Artifactory doesn't have an option to do this. Marking this as the answer since it gives a workaround. Thanks.